# Is it possible to duplicate an item in Stardew Valley?

Tags: stardew-valley, cheats

I was wondering if you could possibly duplicate items in Stardew Valley.

I want to try to make a really good farm layout, but obviously don't have all the resources for it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is, yes, though it may depend on what device you're playing the game on. The 'Stardew Valley Item ID Glitch' allows you to spawn items that you can then sell to generate resources you want. You can perform it by naming either your character or an animal you own after the game's item codes. By doing this, the item will spawn every time that name is referenced (so, whenever you talk to the animal). Also, you can find all game item codes [at this website](https://stardewids.com/). So, for example:

- A chicken named [72] will spawn a diamond whenever you talk to it, because diamonds are item 72 in the game code.
- A chicken named [60][64] will spawn an emerald and a ruby when you talk to it, because 60 and 64 are those items' IDs in the game code.

In [an interview with IGN](https://www.ign.com/articles/2017/10/24/stardew-valley-dev-says-bizarre-helpful-bug-wont-be-patched), the Stardew Valley developer confirmed he finds this glitch charming and doesn't plan to patch it out, so it can be used without fear:

> “I am aware of it, but I don’t think I want to fix it,” Barone said. “It's not game-breaking, it's kind of amusing, and the likelihood that someone would randomly stumble upon it is extremely low. So I feel like it's okay to leave it, and actually kind of fun.”

**However**, this is no longer possible on Switch as of December 2018 ([version 1.3](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Console_Version_History#1.3_2)), as Nintendo mandated that that the glitch be fixed there.

Comment: It is patched in version 1.3 on the Switch: "Fixed item spawn codes allowed in character names. (This was required by Nintendo since it can cause crashes" [link](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Console_Version_History#1.3_2)

Comment: As a software dev, I'm curious on how this bug happens :o

Comment: @SimonArsenault Probably by storing items and other values using strings without specifying their type. Like if a developer used `broken` as an item's name to indicate it won't work, a tool named (by the user) `broken` would immediately break. Or maybe something else, but this seems like the most probable explanation...

Comment: Thanks, @Mathias711, I added that info to the answer.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Accessing items by their name and not their unique ID sounds like a terrible implementation. I can't believe someone experienced would do that. Plus, the fact that you can concatenate multiple IDs to generate multiple items kinda disproves your theory... unless it loops through all items, uses `contains` instead of `equals` and continues looping after finding a match, which seems unlikely. Anyway, as you said, it can be anything, but I'd love a blog post from the author explaining it :)

Comment: @SimonArsenault My guess would be, there's a database of strings for dialogue and such stored separately from the game's code, and the devs wanted a way to embed "and at this point in the dialogue, the character gives you an X" into those strings. So when the dialogue-printing function sees [X] in a string, it spawns an X instead of printing it. They just didn't realize that player-chosen NPC names would allow the player to run their own arbitrary strings through the dialogue-printer…

Comment: (Which is probably also why it can cause crashes, if it wasn't intended for player use, so they never hardened it to deal with edge cases like "[99999]" or "[99999".)

Comment: @Draconis that actually makes sense!

Comment: You can also name yourself that and I think even your farm. gus says your name a lot and other people will say your name as well on occasion. This will let you get any items you want very early on.

Answer (score 1):

With a full inventory, selecting an item or stack of items in a chest, then clicking the organize button on the chest duplicates the item/stack of items being held. They are dropped on the ground near the chest, and can be collected after freeing up inventory space. When shipped, the duplicated items do not show in the end of day summary screen, but the gold is collected upon starting the next day.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in multiplayer, you can put an item (it cant be placeble, like a sprinkler) in the table and you and your friend(s) grab it together, if done at the correct time, you will end up with two (or more, each player will get one). You can time this and end up with tons of items, and its not so cheaty as the id glitch, beacause its not like a console command, its just a fail in the game